# How to reuse the Parcelable object in Android?

Tags: android, hashmap, parcelable, android-activity

I have the class that implements `Parcelable` interface. That contain `HashMap`, this `HashMap` contains bitmap images. I need this `HashMap` for all my activities. So I used `Parcelable`. Look on my `Parcelable` code.

```
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> map;

        public ParcelFullData() {
            map = new HashMap();
        }

        public ParcelFullData(Parcel in) {
            map = new HashMap();
            readFromParcel(in);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public ParcelFullData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new ParcelFullData(in);
            }

            public ParcelFullData[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ParcelFullData[size];
            }
        };

        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(map.size());
            for (String s: map.keySet()) {
                dest.writeString(s);
                dest.writeValue(map.get(s));
            }
        }

        public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            int count = in.readInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                map.put(in.readString(), (Bitmap)in.readValue(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader()));
            }
        }

        public Bitmap get(String key) {
            return map.get(key);
        }

        public String[] getKeys() {
            Set<String> mapset = map.keySet();
            String[] photoName = new String[mapset.size()];
            Iterator<String> itr = mapset.iterator();
            int index = 0;
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String name = itr.next();
                photoName[index] = name;
                index++;
            }
            return photoName;
        }

        public void put(String key, Bitmap value) {
            map.put(key, value);
        }

        public HashMap<String, Bitmap> getHashMap() {
            return map;
        }
```

This will working fine when i pass the one `Activity` to another `Activity`.( For example `Activity A` to `Activity B`.) But If I pass this to another Activity( For example `Activity B` to `Activity C`.) means that `HashMap` contains no elements. That size is 0.

In Activity_A,

```
Intent setIntent = new Intent(activity_a, Activity_B.class);

ParcelFullData parcelData = new ParcelFullData();

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("parcelData", parcelData);
startActivity(setIntent);
```

In Activity_B

```
ParcelFullData parcelData = (ParcelFullData)bundle.getParcelable("parcelData");

Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeParcelable(parcelData , 0);
parcelData.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
Intent setIntent = new Intent(activity_a, Activity_B.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("parcelData", parcelData);
startActivity(setIntent);
```

I'm doing the same in `Activity C`.

How to use resolve this?

Comment: How and where do you obtain and pass further this parcelable object? Can you provide the code here?

Comment: check out [this one](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/)

Comment: @ Lalit, I already seen that. But Its working fine on one activity to another Activity. But How to use multiple Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `bundle`? You don't add this bundle to intent. Use `Intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)` and everything will be OK. I pass one `Parcelable` object through all activities in my app and it works fine.

In first activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity_a, Activity_B.class);
i.putExtra("parcelData", parcelData);
```

In second activity:

```
parcelData = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcelData");
// ... do anything with parcelData here
Intent i = new Intent(activity_b, Activity_C.class);
i.putExtra("parcelData", parcelData);
```

Comment: @ Jin, Got it. I used `Bundle`. This is the problem. Now its working.